# Concatenate many rows into a single text string in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

Consider a database table holding names, with three rows:

```
SubjectID      StudentName
---------      -------------
 1             Peter
 2             Paul
 2             Mary
```

Is there an easy way to turn this into a single string in entity framework? something like this:

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Peter
2               Paul, Mary
```

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) to more information.

Comment: 1) what have you tried? 2) the inputs/outputs don't match! 3) your output example is arbitrary. what's the logic?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string for more info

Comment: That link is irrelevant.

Comment: I change output in my question

Comment: Your example output still defies your request. _What do you want, and where are you stuck with it?_

Comment: @GrantThomas Please Check again

Comment: @HosseinMoradinia Shouldn't it be Paul, Marry against SubjectID 2 in your example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to group your students by subject:

```
var result = StudentSubjects
                .GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID)
                .Select(x => new 
                    { 
                        Subject = x.Key, 
                        Names = String.Join(", ", x.Select(n => n.Name)) 
                    });
```

I have used [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to concatenate the list of names.

Comment: I got error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join

Comment: This code wouldn't work unless you call `ToList()` or `ToListAsync(cancelationToken)` before `.Select()`. But doing so will also harm the performance of the query.